# Strange tooltip behavior with long series in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts for a project in which I have to display two series with about a thousand points each. The x-axis represents a date, and the y-axis a quantity. In addition, each point has an associated list of namesMy data is day-by-day without gaps, with a structure such as

```
var mydata = [ ...
               {x: theDate, y: theValue, names: theNames},
               ... ]
```

where `theNames` is an array of strings. I can access these in the tooltip formatter through `this.points.point.names`, *given that the range displayed on the chart is small enough*. If I change the x-axes so that the start date and end date are more than roughly a year apart, then the tooltip is not rendered at all.

One of the possible avenues that I have tried but failed with so far is setting the turboThreshold limit to the length of the longest series plus 1. Setting this lets me at least display a graph when `mydata.length > 1000` (the default value). However, this only displays the tooltip if the x-axis range is less than 261. Otherwise, the tooltip disappears entirely, as does the `point.data` object where I'm getting the name from.

I'm also not great at JavaScript, but I was wondering if there were a way to separate the names of the points from the array containing them (in my examples, `myData1` and `myData2`) and somehow access those names from the tooltip function without going through the current point.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/34tfg/) is the link to the jsFiddle demonstrating this issue.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Also, the actual value depends on the browser and the data being displayed... for instance, in my actual project, the upper bound for days displayed (with one value per day) is 379 days, and on a friend's computer on Safari with the same data, the maximal number of days is 326.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in dataGrouping, when disabled works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/34tfg/1/

DataGrouping is method in Highcharts to approximate points and display them when width of the chart is not enough, e.g. how to display 10 000points in a chart of width 1 000px -> 10 points in a one pixel..? And when dataGrouping is used, new points are created, so all your custom options like 'names' etc. are lost (at least not accessible).

Code:

```
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            },
            turboThreshold: 10000
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems to be the solution.